# When exactly is the MMU accessed on x86?

Tags: memory-management, x86, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, mmu

Is it called during the execution of an instruction itself (after it has been fetched & decoded)?

Or does it happen beforehand (however is it possible until we know that something is a (virtual) address?..)

Or does the CPU access the MMU at some other moment?..

My basic understanding is that the CPU decodes an instruction, gets a virtual address, calls the MMU to convert it to physical one, then the CPU operates (loads/stores etc.) on the physical address.

Is it correct?

Comment: Mostly, there is no "call", it is looking up a table (memory chunk x to user chunk y) provided by de os that contains the heap(s)/program to translate

Comment: Code-fetch needs an iTLB hit (with a miss triggering a page walk); data load/store instructions *also* check the dTLB (again with a miss triggering a page walk).  For a memory-destination instruction like `add [rax], ecx`, that TLB check happens on both the load and store uops separately.  "The MMU" isn't a separate part of the CPU, it's tightly integrated into parts of each core.   See [VIPT Cache: Connection between TLB & Cache?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46480015) and CPU deep-dives like https://www.realworldtech.com/merom/3/ although the latter assumes you know the basics of what has to happen

Comment: A data load and/or store instruction typically doesn't access its own machine code, so it needs to translate a different address than code-fetch anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it called during the execution of an instruction itself (after it has been fetched & decoded)?

For the original 80386; (if paging is enabled) whenever the CPU needs to access virtual memory it would use page directories then page tables to determine the correct physical address/es. E.g. for an instruction like "`mov eax,[ebx]`" the CPU would convert the linear address of the instruction into a physical address, then fetch the instruction, then convert the address in `ebx` into a physical address and fetch the data. Worse; if something is split across a page boundary (e.g. first half of the instruction at the end of one page, last half of the same instruction on the next page) the CPU might need to convert 2 linear addresses into physical addresses to get both pieces.

This seems relatively slow now; but back then the speed of cache (and the speed of RAM) was closer to the speed of the CPU, so it wasn't as bad as it seems.

As CPUs got faster the cost of converting linear addresses into physical addresses became more of a problem. For 80486 there were 2 changes to help this - caches were added to the CPU itself (instead of being an external part on the motherboard) to speed cache up, and TLBs (Translation Look-aside Buffers) were added to cache previously done "linear address to physical address" translations. The TLBs helped a lot - if there's a "TLB hit" the CPU can skip accessing the page directory (from cache or RAM) then skip accessing the page table (from cache or RAM). Of course if there's a "TLB miss" it will still have to do all the work to convert a linear address into a physical address (and cache the translation in the TLB).

As time went by the fundamental concept remained the same but everything grew - more larger caches, more larger TLBs. Then (for 64-bit) the number of "levels of tables" grew to 4 (page map level 4, page directory pointer table, page directory, page table) and the cost of "TLB miss" increased. To help cope with that Intel added higher level translation caches (e.g. to cache page directory pointer table entries) so if there's a TLB miss but a "higher level translation cache hit" it could avoid some of the memory accesses (e.g. avoid fetching from PML4 and page directory).

Also Intel started getting more advanced with L1 instruction cache - adding extra tags to each cache line so they could skip conversion for instruction fetches.

I should also point out that a lot of this happen in parallel while a CPU is also doing other things (CPU could be fetching some instructions while decoding other instructions while doing linear to physical address translation for other instructions while ...); which also helps to hide the cost of linear to physical address translation.

Comment: Huh, `invlpg` was new in 486, the 386 didn't even have a mechanism for managing a TLB (unless it was coherent with stores to the page table).  I'm surprised, I assumed every CPU with virtual memory would at have at least a tiny TLB, since even cache-hit page-walks on every access seems like it'd be a performance disaster.  How much slower was 80386 on any typical benchmarks or workloads with paging enabled vs. disabled in protected mode?  (Say a 386DX with a 32-bit bus, to reduce memory bottlenecks.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I386#Architecture shows it had a code prefetch queue (16 bytes).  I'd hope it only re-checked the page tables for code fetch when it's in a different page than before (or maybe always after a taken branch/jump); that could save a *lot* of redundant memory access within basic blocks, especially in code that mostly works with registers.  But at worst it would still be fetching 4 aligned bytes at a time, not re-checking the page tables for every instruction.  (32-bit mode average instruction length is often well below 4 bytes, especially before MMX/SSE existed)

Comment: But re-checking the MMU for each instruction is a useful simplification.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm not sure about speed (a little before my time, and operating systems didn't really use it much until later). 80x86 has a 15-byte max. instruction length; so a 16-byte prefetch buffer is only slightly more than the minimum needed to ensure 1 instruction can be prefetched (and to simplify the "split across page boundaries"). I'd guess they rotated the 16-byte buffer and refilled by fetching a minimum of a word, so sometimes (e.g. if 16 bytes were in use before a 1-byte instruction got executed) you'd end up with an "15 bytes used + unfilled byte" to avoid a 1 byte fetch.

Comment: I've read 8086 is the same way: not starting a 1-byte instruction fetch cycle if there's only 1 byte of space in the buffer.  But note that 8088's 4-byte prefetch queue is shorter than 6-byte `add word [bx+0x1234], 0x5678`, so at least in that older generation, the whole instruction didn't need to be ready, even after decoding prefixes separately.  386 easily could have changed that, though.  But as recently as P5 Pentium, prefixes took an extra cycle to decode, IIRC, so they might still do that separately.

Comment: Correction to my earlier comments and the answer: **386 had a TLB**, and `mov eax, cr3` / `mov cr3, eax` was how it invalidated all TLB entries when necessary.  486's `invlpg` was an optimization to only invalidate stuff related to one linear virtual address.  See [How were the test registers used on the i386 and the i486?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21963) for evidence of 386 having a TLB (and special registers to query them.)

Comment: This also came up on [How can a 32-bit x86 CPU start with reset vector 0xFFFFFFF0 even though it starts in 16-bit real mode?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27035)/ recently where Stephen Kitt corrected my answer's assertion that 386 lacked a TLB.  (Comments are now deleted, but I think this was where I got the misinformation :/)